# how to a detect whole word in a string using stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to detect a whole word using `str_detect`. It should be simple, but I can't get it right...
This should return `FALSE`, but it returns `TRUE`.

`str_detect("Baumer PBMN PTransmitter 0-600bar#324664",pattern="600")`

and adding `boundary` threw an error

`str_detect(string="Baumer PBMN PTransmitter 0-600bar#324664",
pattern="600",boundary("word"))`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean `str_detect("Baumer PBMN PTransmitter 0-600bar#324664",'\\b600\\b')` ?

Comment: Thanks, that works, I thought there was an easy solution. Can you answer the question so I can accept it?

Comment: If the pattern is a variable how would be concatenate the pattern?
``pn <- "600"
str_detect("Baumer PBMN PTransmitter 0-600bar#324664",'\\b pn \\b')``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can add word boundaries as `\\b`. If the `pattern` is variable we can use `paste0` to concatenate it with word boundaries.

```
pn <- "600"
stringr::str_detect("Baumer PBMN PTransmitter 0-600bar#324664", paste0('\\b', pn, '\\b'))
#[1] FALSE
```

The same can also be done using `grepl`

```
grepl(paste0('\\b', pn, '\\b'), "Baumer PBMN PTransmitter 0-600bar#324664")
```