# How to grep from patterns in one dataframe for another?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataset which is just a list of genes:

```
Genes
Gene1
Gene2
Gene3
Gene4
Gene5
```

I am looking to find and pull out from another dataset any time any of these genes are mentioned.

My other dataset looks like

```
Study ID   Title                  Drug        ...
1         Study of Gene1         Gene1-drug
2         Study of Gene10        Gene10-drug
3         Study of something     Gene4-drug
```

I am looking to pull out any time a gene appears in any column of my 2nd dataset.

I'm having difficult finding a similar enough question to re-use, although I know there are many similar questions, but I am missing something, most examples I find have a specific pattern to grep.

So far I've been trying:

```
test = df[apply(df, 1, function(i) any(stringr::str_detect(i, fixed(genelist)))),]
```

This outputs 0 rows but I know there are rows that have the partial matches where the genes are mentioned. How can I amend this to pick up and search for the genes from the gene list dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I suggest you is with `purrr`.

1. Make each row of the dataframe as one string
2. Detect in each row if one of the words in `df_genes$Genes` is there
3. Wrap up the result

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

rows <- pmap(df, str_c, sep = " ") %>% 
  map(str_detect, paste0('\\b', df_genes$Genes, '\\b')) %>% 
  map_lgl(any)
df[rows,]
#>   Study_ID              Title       Drug
#> 1        1     Study of Gene1 Gene1-drug
#> 3        3 Study of something Gene4-drug
```

The `paste0` + `\\b` idea comes from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626073/how-to-a-detect-whole-word-in-a-string-using-stringr)

---

INPUT DATA:

```
df_genes <- data.frame(Genes = c("Gene1",
                                 "Gene2",
                                 "Gene3",
                                 "Gene4",
                                 "Gene5"))

df <- data.frame(Study_ID = 1:3,
                 Title = c("Study of Gene1",
                           "Study of Gene10",
                           "Study of something"),
                 Drug = c("Gene1-drug",
                          "Gene10-drug",
                          "Gene4-drug"))
```

---

Check which genes were found in each row with this:

```
pmap(df, str_c, sep = " ") %>% 
  map(str_detect, paste0('\\b', df_genes$Genes, '\\b')) %>% 
  map(~keep(df_genes$Genes, .))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Gene1"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "Gene4"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help again! This answers my question, if possible, do you know if there's a way to find which genes from my list have been identified as matches in the datatset? No worries if not, I'll have a go myself at that now, thanks for all your help!

Comment: I swear: I didnt do it on purpose to answer all your questions today ahah. Anyway, check out my last edit.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely appreciate it regardless!  I have another, and last, question: I've just realised I need to make it only pick matches that are upper case (my real genes are all upper case). I've tried ```matchedgenestest <- pmap(df, str_c, sep = " ") %>% 
  map(grepl, paste0('\\b', genelist$Gene, '\\b', ignore.case = F)) %>% 
  map(~keep(genelist$Gene, .))
``` but this doesn't work

Comment: Set everything to lower. It’s easier.